# Make react routers secure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want my react application to be secured by login. I have 3 screens in my react application. But non of the urls of each screen is secured. I can directly enter the url for any page and localhost take me to the corresponding page. What I want is unless a user is logged in, whenever he enters any url other than main url(which directs to login screen) he should be redirected to login screen first.

I have already tried few things. Like I have my routers like this

```
function authorize(){
    console.log('inside')
    if(window.localStorage.token == undefined) {

        browserHistory.push('/')
    }
}
function getRoutes(store) {

    return (
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={LoginPage}/>
            <Route path='app' component={App}  onEnter={()=>{authorize()}}>
                <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                <Route path='/video-screen' component={VideoScreen}>
                    <IndexRoute component={TagList}/>
                    <Route path='/add' component={AddTags}/>
                    <Route path='/TagList' component={TagList}/>
                    <Redirect from='*' to='/'/>
                </Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    )
}
export default getRoutes;
```

And I am storing my login token from login screen like this. This is from my login component where I make ajax call to api which returns a token on successful login.

```
$.ajax(settings).done((response) => {
            token = response.auth_token;
            window.localStorage.token_auth = token;  //store in localstorage
            this.context.router.push('/app')
        });
```

But after doing this when I go to my localhost:3000/app url without logging in, it takes me to the page and doesn't redirect me to login page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you go in the if condition? Do you get an error push of undefined?

Comment: No. I don't get something like that

Answer (score 0):

Im using this method in my project, basicly you have all private routes wrapped in route with component wich controls if user is logged.

I used method with onEnter as you do, but then the component will mount whatever you are logged in or not.

```
// routes.js
<Route path='books' component=...>
<Route component={CheckLogin}>
  <Route path='secret-books' component=.../>
</Route>

// ChcekLogin.js
// stateless component 
function ChcekLogin({isLogged, children}){
  if(isLogged)
    return children

  return <div>Logged users only</div>
}
```